# How to replace or update existing values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I imported an access database to mysql. The mysql database was for building my application using asp.net mvc 3. Since my access values has changed, I am looking for a way to update mysql database.

My table have over 70 000 records.
I have imported my access database to another table in mysql. Now how do I update those values from one mysql table to another and if there are new records add them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this format ::

```
update
table1 inner join table2 on (//join condition)

set table1.column1=table2.column2

where // the clause
```

Comment: @sashi-kantThe table has more than 70000 records.

Comment: 70000 rows not a problem